# jQuery: "Doesn't have" selector?

Tags: jquery

I see this [has](http://api.jquery.com/has/) selector, where's the `hasnt` selector? I want to find tables that don't contain images.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Something like `$("table:not(:has(img))")`?

Comment: Does that really work?  Can you post a link to the documentation?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). Then you can say:

```
$('selection').not('something-you-don\'t-want')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) method or the [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector.